# Is there a way how to open "change popup" in Idea (PhpStorm)?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

This is the window I would like to open by pressing (ie.) `CTRL+D` shortcut standing when cursor is on proper line. Could not find other than "mouse way"...

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. Never thought about opening that popup using a keyboard shortcut before (probably because I don't use it very much).

A careful investigation of the editor commands in the `Preferences`->`Keymap` window revealed the command `Change under caret` in the `Version Control Systems` group.

It doesn't have any keyboard combination assigned by default; set your preferred keys combination, close the window using the `OK` button and enjoy!